# How to grep -v/--invert-match based on content of file?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm running a bash commando to filter a file using `grep`, `awk` and `xargs`, and I'm happy with the output I'm getting, however I would also like to exclude some lines based on content of an existing file.

E.g

My output

```
IP1 HostX1
IP2 HostY2
IP3 HostY3
IP4 HostY4
IP5 HostY5
IP6 HostY6
IP7 HostX7
```

I want to be able to include `grep -v` based on entire content of a file, e.g
`diff ... | awk ... | xargs ... | grep -v FILE`
The `FILE` looks like:

```
IP2 HostY2
IP3 HostY3
IP4 HostY4
IP5 HostY5
IP6 HostY6
```

Desired output

```
IP1 HostX1
IP7 HostX7
```

Comment: I want to be a "bash commando". :)

Comment: I tagged it with `bash`, but should've specified in my question. I'll improve, however, out of curiosity, how would this be solved in "non-bash" @PaulHodges?

Comment: I'd like to see more of the actual command pipeline. I understand that you may have been using `awk` to format input to `xargs` and then `grep` to select from the results, but I try to avoid using both in a pipeline if possible because they are both pattern engines. You might have been able to add a little code in the `awk` to exclude those records from the final output earlier. Neither of those approaches should matter whather you're running under `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `csh`, or most anything in common use. I just liked the typo of `bash commando`! :)

Comment: I like this comment: *I try to avoid using both in a pipeline if possible*.
`diff instances.ip <( uniq local.ip ) | grep '^<' | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs -I% grep -w % instances.tsv`

Comment: First glance, just move the pattrn for the standalone `grep` into the `awk` like this: `diff instances.ip <( uniq local.ip ) | awk '/^</{ print $2 }' | xargs -I% grep -w % instances.tsv` - but you are also spawning (likely multiple) `grep` with `xargs`. I suspect that coul be rolled into an elaborated `awk` as well. Personally, I think I'd `diff` to a file and then use `awk` directly on all the inputs, unless the files are all pretty small, is which case it's really not going to matter so much anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it adding following: `commands ... | grep -v -f FILE`